# Creating Oracle Procedure To Update Table

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I'm trying to create a procedure in an Oracle database that will update the PMBPCSB with an 'X' if any of the other columns have a value present. If all of the columns are NULL then I don't want it to do anything. I'm not exactly sure how to format the procedure to accomplish what I'm wanting. Any help is appreciated.

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| PMBPCSB |  |
| PMBPCFBB |  |
| PMBPCHUB |  |
| PMBCITNC |  |
| PMBCITNSB |  |
| PMBCSDB |  |
| PMBCSDVOS |  |
| PMBCVOSB |  |
| PMBCWOB |  |

Comment: 1. For this table or for any table? 2. Even if someone adds or removes a column from the table?

Comment: 3. "format the procedure" You mean "write the code to produce the table I'm showing below"?

Comment: @Jeff My apologies, it is for this table and we can call the table A1. My intent is to setup a scheduled job that will run each day. I'm the only one that has access to add or remove a column so if in the future that was to happen then I would edit the procedure myself with the changes.

Comment: Why do you want a procedure, rather than, say, using a view, or making it a virtual column calculated from all the other columns?

Comment: You don't need a procedure to produce the output you show. You can do it with a single query. If you don't mind the output being a single row of 18 columns then you don't even need to pivot the output.

Comment: @JeffHolt I think I see what you're saying. I could create a view with a query that will only show results if there is something in any of the columns. Then if there is I would run an Update query to update the PMBPCSB column with an X. Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just an ordinary `UPDATE`, is it not?

```
SQL> create table pm
  2    (pmbpcsb  varchar2(1),
  3     pmbpcfbb varchar2(10),
  4     pmbpchub varchar2(10),
  5     pmbcitnc varchar2(10)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into pm values (null, '100', '200', '300');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into pm values (null, '300', null , '500');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into pm values (null, null , null , null );

1 row created.
```

Update:

```
SQL> update pm set
  2    pmbpcsb = 'X'
  3  where coalesce(pmbpcfbb, pmbpchub, pmbcitnc) is not null;

2 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from pm;

PMBPCSB    PMBPCFBB   PMBPCHUB   PMBCITNC
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
X          100        200        300
X          300                   500
                                            --> this is a row whose columns are NULL (all of them)

SQL>
```

How to *convert* it to a procedure? Simply:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_pm as
  2  begin
  3    update pm set
  4      pmbpcsb = 'X'
  5    where coalesce(pmbpcfbb, pmbpchub, pmbcitnc) is not null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

---

However, perhaps you'd rather use `CASE` and affect all rows because - what if table contents changes?

```
SQL> update pm set
  2    pmbpcsb = case when coalesce(pmbpcfbb, pmbpchub, pmbcitnc) is not null then 'X'
  3                   else null
  4              end;

3 rows updated.

SQL>
```

---

Or, as people commented, create a view (using the same principle):

```
SQL> create or replace view v_pm as
  2  select case when coalesce(pmbpcfbb, pmbpchub, pmbcitnc) is not null then 'X'
  3              else null
  4         end pmbpcsb,
  5     pmbpcfbb,
  6     pmbpchub,
  7     pmbcitnc
  8  from pm;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_pm;

PMBPCSB    PMBPCFBB   PMBPCHUB   PMBCITNC
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
X          100        200        300
X          300                   500


SQL>
```